# Can I use in_array with file()?

Tags: php

I'm using in_array with file(). Sometimes he is only reading the first link in the blocklist.txt file or he isn't reading the file at all.

```
$list = file("include/blocklist.txt");
$url = $_GET["url"];

if (in_array($url, $list)) {
include("include/harmful.inc.php");
} else {
header("Location: " . $_GET["url"]);
}
if (empty($_GET)) {
echo "<p>URL not requested</p>";
}
```

Do I need to use something else than in_array?

Comment: @Rizier123 Good to see you again, Rizier! The script itself works 100%, but it's more user-friendly if the blocklinks can be placed in a txt file. But now this error accurs.. :l

Comment: *But now this error accurs* Which error? You didn't posted one

Comment: which error you are getting??

Comment: @Rizier123 I meant bug, Sorry. I've described it in my post

Comment: @CarlJohnson 1. Check if `$list` is not FALSE 2. If it sometimes only reads the first line, which is very weird, just put a special line at the end and check if the last element of the array `$list` is equal to the special line

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, since `file()` returns an array.

Comment: on fail it returns false, which isn't an array